# Firefox scrollbar appearance

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome, gtk

I have several Linux servers that I use to check changes in appearance of our web app.  I capture automatically screenshots.

I use CentOS 7, Firefox.
All servers are theorically equal, but in one of them, scrollbars are shown differently.  I have installed no firefox extensions.  Size is different.  Firefox version is the same: 56.

In one server, I've installed a Gnome desktop, so it has more Gnome packages.

After some research, I've come to the conclusion that it is something related to GTK 3 theme.

The command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

returns adwaita in both of them.

There is no ~/.theme file.
[image: Server 1, with more gnome packages]
[image: Server 2]

How can I make all the scrollbars look the same for consistent results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I monitorize all files opened by Firefox with the `strace` utility:

```
strace -e trace=open firefox -o tmp/firefox.tmp
```

Then I compare `firefox.tmp` in both computers and I see that the adwaita gtk2 theme isn't installed on one computer.

I perform:

```
yum -y install adwaita-gtk2-theme
```

et voilà they render now scroll bars the same! :-)